# Creating attributes of a NSManagedObject Entity through multiples steps and view controllers using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, segue, nsmanagedobject

If I create a new piece (attribute) of an entity in each view controller before segueing to the next view controller to create another piece of the final entity, how can I pass the data from each view controller to the final view controller that has the option to save the entity.

For example I have an Entity consisting of the following attributes: body, date, category, photo, and goal. Each of these attributes are created in separate view controllers before moving to the next. I don't know how in the final view I can insert a new NSEntityDescription and assign each attribute to the data collected from previous view controllers. What is the best way to pass the data from one vc to the next / pull the info from each one in the final view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going at it the wrong way (in my opinion).

You should do it like this:

1. create a new managed context (main type) as child of the parent: edit context
2. insert a new entity in that context
3. pass the inserted entity reference and edit context to every view controller that build your object
4. apply the changes directly to your inserted object
5. when the user is done, save the edit context (if he cancel, simply discard the context and no harm is done).
6. if you like to persist the changes to the store, also save the parent context (and so forth up to the store)

**Edit:**
There is no issue of a parent child contexts beeing of the same concurrency type (main in this case).

Changes needed in your "App Delegate" (assuming the boilerplate code provided by apple):

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

/**
This will create a disposable context with main queue concurrency type.
The disposable context will have the main context as parent.
Pass this around view controllers while editing the same part of the object graph.
*/
- (NSManagedObjectContext*) editingContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* ctx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    ctx.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return ctx;
}
```

And you should expose the `editingContext` method in the header file of the delegate.

To save (assuming only one parent context):

```
//get an editing context
editingContext = [appDelegate editingContext];

//pass this context to all editing views
//when you are ready to save:

NSError* error = nil;
[editingContext save:&error];
//check for errors
[editingContext.parentContext save:&error];
//check for errors
```

Comment: I completely agree with you that this is the correct way to do it. I have spent the last 45 mins looking trying to understand how to create a managed context as a child of the parent, but as you know every tutorial/post is always different. Since your answer is very logical and exactly what I have been seeking out the past few weeks, could you perhaps provide an example of how I would go about creating a child context in one of the view controllers?

Comment: It's a reasonable question whether you could have a child context where both the child and parent are the default concurrency type.  A lot of what you found no doubt has only one mainQueue MOC.  I wonder whether your child MOC could also be mainQueue.

Comment: @stevesliva There is no problem creating a parent child contexts of the same concurrency type (main in this case)

Comment: Okay so now I have added this code to my appDelegate. In order to call this method in my view controller and pass to the next do I need to instead of saveContext call editing context and then pass it to a NSManagedObjectContext property in the header file of my view controller?

Comment: You need to pass the editing context to your editing views (or hold it storngly in the creating view and only pass the edited object). to save you need to call the `save:` method of the editing context and then the `save:` of the parent context (or the app delegate `saveContext` method after commiting the changes to the parent context).

Comment: okay thanks I've almost got it working now.. one last question.. is this initialized and performed in the prepare for segue method and in the next view controller initialized in viewWillAppear?